# Get the list of classic bluetooth connected devices (no BLE) [EAAccessoryManager]

Tags: ios, external-accessory, ios-bluetooth

I need to do an app which will be able to tell if I am currently connected to a classic Bluetooth device or not (actually, it will be a Bluetooth car device).

My first step is to tell what are the current connected classic Bluetooth devices. I cannot use CoreBluetooth because it's only for LE. I try to use the External Accessory framework.

Here is the code (a button starts the method):

```
- (IBAction)startMethodGetConnected:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"button taped");
     // Get the number of accessories connected
     NSUInteger NumberOfAccessoriesConnected = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager].connectedAccessories count];
     //Display the number 
     NSLog(@"number of accessories connected : %d", NumberOfAccessoriesConnected);
 }
```

I have tried when the iPhone was connected to a Bluetooth keyboard and also with a Bluetooth headset. In both cases, the console displays that the number is 0.

How can I display the correct number?

Comment: It seems that Bluetooth devices like "normal" Keyboard and "normal" Headset are not listed in EAAcessoryManager.

Comment: Yes, I think it's because the device has to be MFI, which may not not be the case for "normal" bluetooth devices. The solution I found was to use the [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs] to get the bluetooth input, however, with this solution, I can not receive notifications while in the background (I would have to play music to be allowed to receive the notification).

Answer (score 1):

From apple documentation:

> "Applications that support external accessories must be sure to
>   configure their Info.plist file correctly. Specifically, **you must
>   include** the *UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols* key to declare
>   the specific hardware protocols your application supports. For more
>   information about this framework, see External Accessory Programming
>   Topics." [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html)

You need to add this key in your Info.plist file with the protocol of your MFi device.

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
<array>
    <string>your_protocol_name</string>
</array>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. What you can do is to check the playback route. The problem is that your cars handsfree will be a HeadsetBT. This is the code I use in my app.

```
// create and set up the audio session
AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setDelegate:self];
[audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];

// set up for bluetooth microphone input
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
OSStatus stat = AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                                         sizeof (allowBluetoothInput),
                                         &allowBluetoothInput
                                         );
NSLog(@"status = %x", stat);    // problem if this is not zero

// check the audio route
UInt32 size = sizeof(CFStringRef);
CFStringRef route;
OSStatus result = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &size, &route);
NSLog(@"route = %@", route);
// if bluetooth headset connected, should be "HeadsetBT"
// if not connected, will be "ReceiverAndMicrophone"
```