# How to get the list of connected bluetooth devices in Xamarin.forms for ios?

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app in which i need to get the list of bluetooth devices.So that i can connect to the desired device and do furthur communication.I am using dependency service.In iOS here is my code:

```
EAAccessoryManager manager = EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager;
var allaccessorries = manager.ConnectedAccessories;
```

In this the variable is allaccessories count is 0.But my ipad is connected with bluetooth printer via bluetooth.

Can anyone suggest me an idea if i am missing anything regarding provisioning profies,info.plist permissions ect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495738/get-the-list-of-classic-bluetooth-connected-devices-no-ble-eaaccessorymanager

Comment: Thanks Cole Xia.It worked for me and i am able to access the bluetooth printer.But I am unable to print the text.I am using StarMicronics Printer

Comment: Ask this question with ios/swift/objective-c tags, then convert answer to c# and use that.